# Keep order in nodejs command line script

Tags: javascript, node.js, io

There is something I want to code in nodejs, but I don't have any idea of how to implement it. I've been reading and searching a lot, and still have not idea of what would be the correct way to do it.

The problem is the following:

- Read lines from stdin
- For each line, launch an http request
- There must be a limit to simultaneous http
- Write the line readed plus some data obtained from the http request to stdout
- Lines must be written in order

You can not read "all" the file and then split lines: you must process one line at a time, remember it's stdin. You don't know when the input will end.

Does anybody have some clues of how to approach this problem? I do not have any idea of how to proceed.

Comment: There is an [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle the simultaneously executed requests with limits are then handle the results when all requests are resolved. For requests you can you the npm module `request` or `request-promise`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
const http = require('http');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
let arrayOfRequests = [];
process.stdin.on('data',  (data) => { 
    //get data from the stdin
    //then add the request to the array
    arrayOfRequests.push(http.get({}))

})

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    Promise.all(arrayOfRequests)
    // use Promise .all to bundle all of the reuqest
    //then use the spread operator so you can use all of the reuqest In order
    .spread( (request1,request2,request3)  => {
        // do stuff
    })
})
```

FYI, the snippet wont work.

So what you are doing is using the `process.stdin` that is built into Node.js. Then you are bundling all of the requests. Whenever the user cancels out of the program, your requests will be made. Since the calls will be async, you have them in an array, then run `Promsise.all` and use the `bluebird` `.spread` operator to deconstruct the `Promise.all` and get the values.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I want to avoid to read all the input before processing it. What if is a very  big file? I think something similar to a blocking queue is needed, I'm researching that.

Comment: I get you want to use a BQ as the DS, but what are you actually trying to do?Do you want to read in the whole file , parse the file, fire all the http requests( up to a certain limit), and then print that out?

Comment: No, I want to read some lines of the files, fire http request upon a certain limit, and when the requests had finished then read more lines of the file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've got this solution for the producer-consumer problem in nodejs, where the producer don't produce more data until there is space available in the queue.

This is queue's code, based on [block-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/block-queue): https://gist.github.com/AlvaroMaceda/8a933a317fed3fd4691fd5eda3e60c5e

To use the blocking queue, you create it with 3 parameters:

1. Number of tasks running concurrently
2. "Push" function. It will be called with the queue as parameter when
   more data is needed. The task will be added with an identifier.
3. "Task" function. It will be called with the identifier created by
   "Push" function.

The queue will call "push" only when more data is needed. For example, if there are five tasks running and it was created with a maximum of 5 concurrent tasks, "push" won't be called until one of these tasks end.

This is an example of how to use it:

```
"use strict";
const queue = require('./block-queue');

const CONCURRENCY = 5;
const WORKS_TO_LAUNCH = 10;
const TIMEOUT = 200;

let i = 1;
let q = queue(CONCURRENCY, doSomethingAsync, putMoreData );

function putMoreData(queue) {
    if (++i <= WORKS_TO_LAUNCH) {
        console.log('Pushing to queue');
        queue.push(i);
    }
}
function doSomethingAsync(task, done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('done ' + task);
        done();
    }, 1000 + task * TIMEOUT);
}

q.push(i);
```

I don't give this as solved because I don't know if there is a more simple approach and I want to work the complete solution, don't know if I'll find some issues when working with this and streams.